# Board to board communication (Backplane) in possible noisy environment- UART, RS232, RS422, RS485?

Tags: pcb, protocol

I've seen alot of references for RS422 and RS485 using cables and twisted pair wiring, but how well do they do over short distances and with just a PCB layout (no cables at all) ? Do people do that ? Is it recommended ?

If I'm looking to create a bus to communicate with 5+ more boards all connected to a backplane, what would be the suggested protocol ?

Comment: What are you going to house these boards in? Is the enclosure going to offer any kind of shielding?

Comment: it will be in some kind enclosure, but I dont know what kind of sheilding it will provide

Comment: Unless your system is insanely noisy and very badly designed you really shouldn't need to consider this.

Answer (score 4):

For medium and low speed signals (UART, I<sup>2</sup>C, etc.), the direct approach of using logic-level signals is usually fine. You just need to make sure that the signals being driven onto the backplane have sufficient drive for the maximum anticipated load. Use buffers if necessary. You can add a ground plane to your backplane to help shield it, if the enclosure it's in isn't sufficient.

For high-speed signals (SPI, etc.), you can still use logic levels, but now the lines start to behave as transmission lines. You need to pay more attention to trace impedances, stray capacitance (particularly in connectors) and crosstalk.

For really high bandwidth, the trend is to use LVDS signalling; PCIe is one example of this.

Answer (score 3):

Using special interfaces like RS485 and similar inside the board is simply pointless and over-engineered. The PCB itself (if properly designed of course) provides some noise suppression - by proper grounding, ground plains, routing the tracks near the ground or in the internal layers, etc.

**Observation:** You simply can't connect all pins by RS485, after all.

If the environment is very, very (very) noisy (rare case) you must provide some shielding of the whole PCB, because the remaining tracks will be vulnerable as well. (see the observation above).

Answer (score 1):

> If I'm looking to create a bus to communicate with 5+ more boards all
>   connected to a backplane, what would be the suggested protocol ?

If the 5+ daughter boards are **already** designed **and** they use RS485 then it makes sense to route 485 across the backplane as tracks. RS 485 needs terminations (120 ohm is standard) and the backplane "slots" for the two furthest points should have terminators fitted.

Loop the 485 tracking from one end of the backplane to the other observing impedance rules for PCB tracks. Try not to create spurs that are too long. There are a few on-line calculators that will give you track dimensions to suit 120 ohms impedance.

If your daughter cards are not designed then using a non-differential bus is probably easier and won't be a problem providing you haven't got some extreme power current requirements that could interfere with the data.